# What does this symbol mean "?->" in php, within an object or null value

Tags: php, php-8

Could you please explain what does the operator `?->` do in PHP, since I have this piece of code:

```
$drive = $objDrive?->func?->getDriver()?->value;
```

Comment: The answer to this question should be placed in [What does this symbol mean?](/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php).

Comment: as far as I know, it is a new operator in the programming language, thanks for your suggestion

Comment: The code you have written there will not work in any released version of PHP, and may or may not ever do so. The feature was only officially proposed yesterday, and hasn't even been discussed yet.

Answer (score 5):

For the moment, it's just a proposal, you can find it [enter link description here](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/nullsafe_calls). It's the `NullSafe Operator`, it returns `null` in case you try to invoke functions or get values from `null`... Example

```
$objDrive = null;
$drive = $objDrive?->func?->getDriver()?->value; //return null
$drive = $objDrive->func->getDriver()->value; // Error: Trying to get property 'func' of non-object
```

Comment: Can you move this answer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)? That is the canonical place for these type of questions.

Comment: I believe it's better to have it (also) as a separate answer since it will be much easier to find.

Comment: @JohnConde idk how to do it aha feel free to do it

Comment: @Berto99 Just copy and paste it :) I'll do that now

Comment: @Andreas yes, so do I, so than if google index it, or someone search for that operator, it can be found here, and so it has not to read the whole page

Comment: @Andreas That other question is what we use for all questions about PHP symbols since they are hard to search for. Stack Overflow does not like answers being duplicated and wants one canonical source for all knowledge wherever possible.

Comment: @JohnConde for what i can see there i can find the operator approved, not the proposed, so if you think that that page is the place where this answer should be, feel free to copy it and paste it on that page

Comment: @JohnConde *...PHP symbols since they are hard to search for.* But also impossible to find on that page. *- what does this mean?* And someone replies with duplicate of 60 pages. Not easy for someone to find something there. Sure easy for closing but not easy for the one asking.

Comment: @Andreas This is what the community has decided should be done and it has worked very well. If you want to change this you can bring it to meta but I don't think you will receive a warm response.

Comment: @JohnConde posted on that page

Comment: @JohnConde I personally super-hate the canonicals that are a mile long.  I have found a more specific duplicate and added to the list.